# sweet alert does not appear when the input process is successful

Tags: sweetalert2

I have 1 problem, I want to display a sweet alert when the input process is successful then the page will move to the main page, I tried this method it didn't work, but if I use  alert('Data Saved Successfully');
window.location/href='index2.php'; succeeded; I made this input not using the database, I just saved it to a json file.

[image: First Image]
[image: Second Image]

I want to display a sweet alert when the input process is successful then the page will move to the main page,